# События родительского элемента распространяются на дочерние

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Вешаю обработчики событий `mouseover` и `mouseout` на *родительский* элемент.
Ожидаю, что `mouseover` сработает только при попадании мыши в область *родительского* элемента, а `mouseout` - только при выходе из области *родительского* элемента.

Но, при перемещении по *дочерним* элементам, срабатывает обработчик `mouseout`, как будто я покинул *родительский* элемент.

*HTML*:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="photo">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="#">
    </a>
    <p class="description">...</p>
    <a href="#">...</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

*JS*:

```
$('.gallery').on('mouseover', '.photo', function() {
    console.log('mouseover');
});

$('.gallery').on('mouseout', '.photo', function() {
    console.log('mouseout');
});
```

[Полный пример в fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwjhr1s8/).

Как сделать так, чтобы обработчики, повешенные на *родительский* элемент, не отрабатывали при перемещении по *дочерним* элементам?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Событий не два, а четыре: mouseenter, mouseleave, mouseover, mouseout.
Ты выбрал не ту пару.

https://jsfiddle.net/dwjhr1s8/3/

```
$('.gallery').on('mouseenter', '.photo', function(){
    console.log('mouseenter');
}).on('mouseleave', '.photo', function(){
    console.log('mouseleave');
});
```

Comment: За что минус-то?

Comment: Не знаю, кто поставил, я плюсовал

Answer (score 2):

В jQuery для этого есть специальная функция `.hover()`, которая является обработчиком событий `mouseenter` и `mouseleave`:

```
$('.gallery .photo').hover(
    function(evt) {   
        alert('mouseenter');
    },
    function(evt) {
        alert('mouseleave');
    }
);
```

[Полный пример в fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwjhr1s8/4/).

Comment: @Regent, да, Вы правы, правильнее называть это так, ошибся.

Comment: @pavelchervov, этот код не вешает живые обработчики, как было у тебя и как реализовано в моём ответе. Это вариант хуже.

Comment: @Qwertiy, мой ответ аналогичен Вашему и ничем не хуже. Так написано в исходном коде jQuery:
        `hover: function( fnOver, fnOut ) {
  return this.mouseenter( fnOver ).mouseleave( fnOut || fnOver );
 }`. А вот [документация](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) на `mouseenter`.

Comment: `$('.gallery .photo').hover(` - у тебя обработчики вешаются на существующие на момент подписки `.gallery .photo` (на каждый из них), а у меня `$('.gallery').on('mouseenter', '.photo',` - т. е. вешается один обработчик на `.gallery`, который срабатывает для всех `.photo` внутри. У автора вопроса такой же вариант, как у меня - событие живое, а не только для тех элементов, которые уже созданы. А твой вариант не будет работать в случае динамического добавления элементов `.photo` после подписки.

Comment: @Qwertiy вопрос только в том, динамичен ли HTML у автора. Если статичен, то этот вариант не хуже, а, может, и чуть лучше в плане производительности. Автор мог использовать делегирование просто потому, что не знает других способов добавить обработчик события. Я это к чему: пока автор не написал, что соответствующий HTML генерируется динамически, нельзя сказать, что этот ответ хуже.

Comment: @Regent, галерея же почти всегда динамическая. В любом случае, насколько я знаю, один обработчик с делегированием по производительности считается более эффективным, особенно для старых браузеров.

Comment: @Rolandius, Qwerty, Regent, внесу ясность: хоть в моем случае галерея и статическая, но, я уже давно взял за правило вешать "живые" обработчики на родительский контейнер. Решение предложенное Rolandius я, толком не разобравшись, признал лучшим, но, поскольку оно действительно вешает обработчики на дочерние элементы, я, всё-таки признаю лучшим ответом ответ Qwertiy.
Всем спасибо за участие!